# Get html date input type value and a value from dropdown to show in other div without loading page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am taking a date and a slot time input from user in a card from user.

```js
$("#online_meeting_datepicker_continue").click(function() {
  $("#online_meeting_user_details").delay(250).fadeIn(250);
  $("#online_meeting_datepicker").fadeOut(250);

});
```

```html
<input type="date" value="<?php echo $today; ?>" id="schedule" class="form-control d-inline" name="schedule">

<select class="form-control d-inline" id="mail_type" name="" required>
  <option value="" selected>4 pm</option>
  <option value="">5 pm</option>
  <option value="">6 pm</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-info form-control" id="phone_call_datepicker_continue"> Continue</a>
```

In new fadein div I want to print the selected date and time using js.what will be the code in new online_meeting_user_details div  for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .val() to the values of your `schedule` and `mail_type`.

Read more about `.val()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Store the value in variable named as `schedule` and `mail_type`

Lastly, when you select date and time you will click continue to `fadeIn` and you will `.html()` to show the selected values.

Read more about `.html()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Run snippet below to see it working

```js
$("#phone_call_datepicker_continue").click(function() {

  //Get selected schedule and mail type
  var schedule = $('#schedule').val()
  var mail_type = $('#mail_type').val()

  //New div data
  var data = '<span>Schedule: ' + schedule + '</span><br><span>Mail Type: ' + mail_type + '</span>'

  //Fade in and show data
  $("#online_meeting_user_details").delay(250).fadeIn(250).html(data);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="<?php echo $today; ?>" id="schedule" class="form-control d-inline" name="schedule">

<select class="form-control d-inline" id="mail_type" name="" required>
  <option disabled selected>Choose One</option>
  <option value="4 pm">4 pm</option>
  <option value="5 pm">5 pm</option>
  <option value="6 pm">6 pm</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-info form-control" id="phone_call_datepicker_continue"> Continue</a>


<div id="online_meeting_user_details"></div>
```